# How to clone a Django project without breaking it?

Tags: django, git

I built a (relatively simple) Django project following a tutorial (the recently released Hello Web App book.) I committed my changes along each step of the way, and I have my working solution in a github repo. However, when I clone the code into a new work space such as onto a new machine or into a new slot on a cloud IDE, the app doesn't work. I get a few errors and with each I resolve, another pops up. Basically, my environment is totally messed up and incompatible with the app beyond having Python and Django both installed.

I realize that I can read through the error messages I get when I invoke runserver, solve each one by one, etc. but it seems there should be a cleaner/simpler way to be able to pull down my repo to a fresh workspace and have it up and running in just a minute or two. I've read recommendations about using virtualenv, but it also seems like people discourage including venv inside your repo because of the extraneous commits and added bulk that will result from it so I don't think that actually solves my problem of trying to reduce new workspace configuration effort.

Perhaps I am overly optimistic, but I'm hoping someone can give me a recommendation to avoid the need to workout these kinks each time I start fresh.

Comment: Git clone is usually clean and simple if you included what some of those errors are people might be in a better position to help. IT's more than likely that the dependencies are not met in your other server or the python and django versions are different.

Comment: An example of an error I'm getting when running python manage.py migrate:

(cut out a big block here)

"/home/ubuntu/workspace/projects/hellowebapp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.

Comment: Extremely likely that your new server uses 1.8 while the dev server had something older. type django-admin --version on both to compare. Old compare python versions wit python --version

Comment: It looks like doing pip install -r requirements.txt (I had dumped my packages here as instructed by the tutorial) helped significantly. However, it still feels pretty clunky and perhaps not completely reliable. I'd love to know the best practices for this kind of thing.

Comment: using a virtualenv and pip in the manner you have done is definitely the right way. Painless 99.9% of the time. Also make sure that the virtualenv has the exact same version of python as in the dev server. There are some distros that still ship with 2.6.x while 2.7.x is more common.